# Error in Continous Deployment of docker container from Azure Container registry to Azure Function

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, azure-container-registry

currently I have a problem with the CD of a docker container to the azure function. The workflow is basically like this:

1. a change is uploaded to azure devops.
2. CI pipeline runs to push image to the azure container registry.
3. CD pipeline runs to update Azure function.

To make it work step 3 has to be skipped and manually change the tag in the implementation center of the azure function. Otherwise, the error below in the images seems to happen every time:

[image]

The code doesn't appear in the azure function.

Comment: Does it work before？ Have you checked this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml%2Ccsharp

Answer (score 0):

**I have followed below steps, and it worked for me.**

Step 1: create a service principle in the App registration.

[image]

Please refer this link for detailed steps to create service principle: [Create a service principal in Azure - Microsoft Purview | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/create-service-principal-azure).

Make note of ClientID and Client secret.

Step 2: Navigate to container registry > Access Control (IAM) > Role Assignment

[image]

Click on Add Role button > Add role assignment

[image]

Choose AcrPull and click Next to create.

Step 3: Navigate to function app > Configuration settings.

Add these two values.

DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = < Paste spn client secret which copied in step 1>

DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = < Paste client id of spn >

After making these changes I will be able to access the function apps.